# How do I change this line of code from R to Python

Tags: r, python-3.x

This is the line of code I need to change:

```
which(!is.na(match(tbl$col1,arr)))
```

I am a newbie to python, would really appreciate the help

Comment: Questions like this get help a lot faster if you (a) explain what the line of code does and (b) provide a little bit of sample input and desired output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler way to achieve the same objective in R:

```r
which(tbl$col1 %in% arr)
```

which can be translated to Python (I'm considering that `tbl` is a Pandas dataframe here):

```py
import numpy as np
np.where(tbl[col1].isin(arr))[0]
```

You should remember that Python is 0-indexed, though.